# If one digit of a specific number is divisible by the other digit .d

Tags: c++

So I want to make a code that checks if one digit of a number is divisible by the other for example: 39. It should print YES since 9 is divisible by 3 9/3=0. But for the number 64 it should print NO since 6 isn't divisible by 4 and 4 isn't divisible by 6. Here's my code I don't know why its not working.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int x,y,z;
   cin >> x;
   y=x/10;
   z=x%10;
   if(y/z==0 || z/y==0)
   {
       cout<<"YES";
   }
   else
   {
       cout<<"NO";
   }
}
```

Comment: You want `y % z == 0 || z % y == 0`. `%` being the remainder of a division, so to check if a number is divisible by another, just check the remainder.

Comment: Add a `cout` printing values of `y` and `z` and you'll find out the problem.

Comment: `a/b` is zero if `a` is less than `b`.

Comment: @AnoopRana Y=3 and Z=9 its supposed to be like that still don't know the problem.

Comment: @molbdnilo exactly thats why I used %

Comment: @ChrisMM I dont understand what you are trying to say. I am checking if the remainder is 0 which is checking the remainder am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @hazey2 Where exactly in `y/z==0 || z/y==0` did you do that? (This condition is a convoluted `y != z`.)

Comment: Will the number only be 2 digits or can it be more?

Comment: @davidg only 2 digits

Comment: @hazey2 Then CrisMM's answer is right.

Comment: ohh I think i understand now if you cant do the division it will count it as 0 right? so its basically always guaranteed to be 0 @DavidG Thank You.

Comment: Hey @DavidG do you know why when I submit the problem on code forces it said runtime error?

Comment: @hazey2 Send me the link the problem

Comment: https://codeforces.com/group/KyZrgaP2rm/contest/372428/problem/D @DavidG

Comment: @hazey2 I'm not allowed to view the contest.

Comment: @DavidG Its ok I figured out how to do the problem and the problem is from code forces not from my code so its good thank you